# Converting Color Correction opencv module example from C++ to python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, colors

I tried to convert color correction module example in https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc1/tutorial_ccm_color_correction_model.html
but I faced some difficulty because I do not know c++,

```
    //compte color correction matrix
    ColorCorrectionModel model1(src, COLORCHECKER_Vinyl);
    model1.run();
    Mat ccm = model1.getCCM();
    std::cout<<"ccm "<<ccm<<std::endl;
    double loss = model1.getLoss();
    std::cout<<"loss "<<loss<<std::endl;
```

I wrote in python as

```
   colorCorrectionModel = cv2.ccm_ColorCorrectionModel(src, cv2.ccm.COLORCHECKER_Macbeth)

   colorCorrectionModel.run()

   ccmat = colorCorrectionModel.getCCM()
   print(ccmat)
   weigths = colorCorrectionModel.getWeights()
   print(weigths)
```

but give me this error

colorCorrectionModel.run()

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-sljz46fi\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:234: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::binary_op'

How I could correct this error

Comment: More people have this problem:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2901

No solution has been reported yet.

Comment: the C++ code (tutorial code on docs.opencv.org) has a column matrix of 3-channel data (Vec3d) because the API expects that kind of data. this shape maps to a numpy shape of `(-1, 1, 3)` (auto rows, 1 column, 3 channels) due to the cv::Mat/np.array conversion logic of OpenCV.

Answer (score 5):

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
detector = cv2.mcc.CCheckerDetector_create()
detector.process(image, cv2.mcc.MCC24, 1)

checkers = detector.getListColorChecker()
for checker in checkers:
    cdraw = cv2.mcc.CCheckerDraw_create(checker)
    img_draw = image.copy()
    cdraw.draw(img_draw)
    
    chartsRGB = checker.getChartsRGB()
    width, height = chartsRGB.shape[:2]
    roi = chartsRGB[0:width,1]
    print (roi)
    rows = int(roi.shape[:1][0])
    src = chartsRGB[:,1].copy().reshape(int(rows/3), 1, 3)
    src /= 255
    #print(src.shape)

    model = cv2.ccm_ColorCorrectionModel(src, cv2.ccm.COLORCHECKER_Macbeth)
    model.setColorSpace(cv2.ccm.COLOR_SPACE_sRGB)
    model.setCCM_TYPE(cv2.ccm.CCM_3x3)
    model.setDistance(cv2.ccm.DISTANCE_CIE2000)
    model.setLinear(cv2.ccm.LINEARIZATION_GAMMA)
    model.setLinearGamma(2.2)
    model.setLinearDegree(3)
    model.setSaturatedThreshold(0, 0.98)
    model.run()

    ccm = model.getCCM()
    print ('ccm:\n{}\n'.format(ccm))
    loss = model.getLoss()
    print ('loss:\n{}\n'.format(loss))

    img_ = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_ = img_.astype(np.float64)
    img_ = img_/255
    calibratedImage = model.infer(img_)
    out_ = calibratedImage * 255
    out_[out_ < 0] = 0
    out_[out_ > 255] = 255
    out_ = out_.astype(np.uint8)
     
    out_img = cv2.cvtColor(out_, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', out_img);

    width, height = image.shape[:2]
    image = cv2.resize(image, (int(height/4),int(width/4)), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    img_draw = cv2.resize(img_draw, (int(height/4),int(width/4)), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    out_img = cv2.resize(out_img, (int(height/4),int(width/4)), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    cv2.namedWindow('Image')
    cv2.imshow("Image",image)
    cv2.imshow('img_draw', img_draw)
    cv2.imshow('Out Image', out_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please provide further context like: How does this code work? How would another user adapt this code to their needs? Which lines are critical for changing the correction algorithm?