# OpenCV Python :

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to implement a color correction algorithm in python using this c++ code as a reference : https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/dc1/tutorial_ccm_color_correction_model.html

Here is the code so far :

```
import cv2

chartype = cv2.mcc.MCC24
image = cv2.imread("image.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

if image is None:
    {
        print("Invalid Image ! \n")
    }

imageCopy = image.copy()
detector = cv2.mcc.CCheckerDetector.create()
# Marker type to detect
if(not detector.process(image,chartype,1)) :
    {
        print("ChartColor not detected \n")
    }

checkers = detector.getListColorChecker()
for checker in checkers :
    cdraw = cv2.mcc.CCheckerDraw.create(checker)
    cdraw.draw(image)
    chartsRGB = checker.getChartsRGB()
    src = chartsRGB[:,1].copy().reshape(3,chartsRGB.rows/3)
```

I face a problem with this line :
`src = chartsRGB[:,1].copy().reshape(3,chartsRGB.rows/3)`
It returns `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rows'`
However, the `getChartsRGB()`  function is supposed to return a `cv2.Map` and not a `numpy.ndarray`
I also tried to cast chartsRGB into a `cv2.Map` (`cv2.Map(chartsRGB)`) but I get the following error messages:

```
AttributeError: 'Mat' object has no attribute 'col'
AttributeError: 'Mat' object has no attribute 'rows'
```

Could anyone help ?

Comment: Python doesn't need `{ }`

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: as I know `Map` is used only in C/C++ but Python converts it into `numpy.array` which is more useful in Python

Comment: if you need number of rows (and columns) then use `rows , cols = chartsRGB.shape[:2]`

Comment: I think you should get the same result using `.reshape(3, -1)` and it will automatically calculate second value

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your comments.
I managed to find the exact answer for this post here : [Converting Color Correction opencv module example from C++ to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66302777/converting-color-correction-opencv-module-example-from-c-to-python)

Answer (score -1):

I guess if you are trying to use the webcam. Please add this line of code
`cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

and apparently `img` is `None` due to no data read.

Change to:

```
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    if img is None:
        break
    imgResult = img.copy()
```

here is the edited code for reference,

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
chartype = cv2.mcc.MCC24
image = cv2.imread("image.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    if image is None:
        {
            print("Invalid Image ! \n")
        }
        break

    imageCopy = image.copy()
    detector = cv2.mcc.CCheckerDetector.create()
    # Marker type to detect
    if(not detector.process(image,chartype,1)) :
        {
            print("ChartColor not detected \n")
        }

    checkers = detector.getListColorChecker()
    for checker in checkers :
        cdraw = cv2.mcc.CCheckerDraw.create(checker)
        cdraw.draw(image)
        chartsRGB = checker.getChartsRGB()
        src = chartsRGB[:,1].copy().reshape(3,chartsRGB.rows/3)
```

Comment: no, he's *not* trying to use a webcam, he's trying to work on an image file. you didn't even read the error message. you didn't even touch the actual issue. OP already found the correct answer on their own. any edits to your answer would now be pointless.